# Test dynamically generated data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, xunit

My test works properly for first and second scenario, but third example (`[MemberData(nameof(SampleData), Error.Key.InvalidParameters)]`) is not launched at all; I am getting an error: `System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.`.

Instead this:

```
[InlineData(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..... }, Error.Key.InvalidParameters)]
```

I want to automatically generate data. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> SampleData()
{
    yield return new object[] { Enumerable.Range(1,200) };
}

[Theory]
[InlineData(new int[] { }, Error.Key.EmptyList)]
[InlineData(new int[] { -5 }, Error.Key.InvalidParameters)]
[MemberData(nameof(SampleData), Error.Key.InvalidParameters)]
public void ExampleTest(IEnumerable<int> ids, Error.Key expected)
{
    // Arrange -> InlineData

    // Act 
    var ex = Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() => sut.SampleValidation(ids));

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected.ToString(), ex.Key);
}
```

Also, I tried this:

```cs
public static (IEnumerable<int>, ValidationError.Key) CombinationData()
{
    yield return (Enumerable.Range(1, 200), ValidationError.Key.InvalidParameters);
}
```

but this gives me an error: `The body of 'SampleData()' cannot be an iterator block because '(IEnumerable<int>, Error.Key)' is not an iterator interface type`

Comment: The test attributes must be compile time constants, you can't invoke a method.

Comment: The `MemberData` xunit attribute generates parameters to be applied as a method call to the test. So it should return `(IEnumerable<int>, Error.Key)` tuples.

Comment: @BurnsBA It doesn't work - I updated question with example you suggested

Comment: Well, lazy language on my part, not a C# tuple type, a set (tuple) of parameters. Check the documentation on MemberData. It's expecting the method to return an enumerable (List), and the list is of type `object[]`.

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/